# Rails Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, active-directory

In my rails app i want to authenticate with an active directory.
I already take a look at Adauth, but i don't know how to do this

I can test the AD with my school Ad: exchange.nhl.nl

Can someone help me with the authentication or maybe having a good tutorial or has a better gem?
And is there in the AD standing a password?

Answer (score 7):

Are you using devise? Then https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable should help you to get started. Since Active Directory is an LDAP server.

There is an older gem, based on the other mentioned specifically for Active Directory: https://github.com/ajrkerr/devise_active_directory_authenticatable It doesn't seem to be maintained, but it still could be useful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [adauth](https://github.com/Arcath/Adauth) gem. It bills itself as

> A Ruby interface for Microsoft's Active Directory based off
>   ruby-net-ldap.

It comes with a generator and can be integrated with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).